# MySQLi update with empty vars/values

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update

I change the MySQL to MySQLi in my code

**BEFORE: mysql (worked fine)**

```
$set = "costAlertVar ='', costAlertSend = ''";
$eintrag = "UPDATE ".$dbprfx."_users SET $set WHERE connection = '$userConnection'";
$eintragen = mysqli_query($eintrag) or die("Error:".mysql_error());;
```

**NOW: mysqli (not working)**

```
$sql = "UPDATE ".$dbprfx."_users SET costAlertVar = ?, costAlertSend = ?  WHERE connection = ?";
$eintrag = $db->prepare( $sql );
$eintrag->bind_param('sss','','',$userConnection);
$eintrag->execute();
$eintrag->close();
```

- costAlertSend = datetime field
- costAlertVar = text field

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli::bind_param` uses the parameters as references, so you have to pass values that can be used as references (i.e. variables).

```
$costAlertVar = '';
$costAlertSend = '';
$eintrag->bind_param('sss',$costAlertVar,$costAlertSend,$userConnection);
```

Comment: Oh yeah! that works! So i have to set everytime a var before bind_param? thx for the quick help

Comment: @user2987790 I would recommend `PDO` strongly over `mysqli` mainly for this reason.